# Codelite Clang Error: No Such File or Directory @./build-Debug

Tags: c, codelite

I have never used Codelite and am attempting to use it as apart of a requirement for "C Programming for Beginners" course on UDEMY.

I am using a Macbook PRO OS version 10.14.5 and Codelite version 14.0.0.

I have created a workspace called SampleApp and within lies a project called Sample with a src file and a main.c file.

The main. c file contains the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, my name is Link\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I build the code I get the following output:

```
/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -j8 -e -f Makefile'
====0 errors, 0 warnings====

Working directory is set to: /Users/link/Desktop/c_code/build-Debug/lib
Executing: open -n -a Terminal /tmp/codelite-exec.sh
Program exited
```

Unfortunately though, when my terminal pops up I get the following error message:

```
22:37:07-link@links-MacBook-Pro:~$ /tmp/codelite-exec.sh ; exit;
/tmp/codelite-exec.sh: line 3: cd: /Users/link/Desktop/c_code/build-Debug/lib: No such file or directory
Hit any key to continue...
```

I am unsure of how to debug this or get this program to run as it appears the target and or the executing directory is not set properly. Kindly advise, thank you.

** **UPDATE** **

There is no lib folder within `/Users/link/Desktop/c_code/build-Debug/lib` .. perhaps that's why the code in `/tmp/codelite-exec.sh` is not working..  Below shows `/tmp/codelite-exec.sh` - line 2 attempts to change directories to the lib folder and execute the Sample workspace but the lib file doesn't exist..

````
#!/bin/bash
command="/Users/link/Desktop/c_code/build-Debug/bin/Sample"
cd /Users/link/Desktop/c_code/build-Debug/lib && ${command}
echo Hit any key to continue...```
````

Comment: Open a terminal and do `ls /Users/link/Desktop/c_code/build-Debug/lib` <- does this exist? Also, try reading the code in `/tmp/codelite-exec.sh` to see what that is doing. It looks like it might produce that directory that it is trying to change into, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Please see my update above to your response ^^

Comment: Can you put the first few lines of the `/tmp/codelite-exec.sh` script in your question? Also, can you include the contents of the `Makefile` ?

Comment: Yes, I  included the code of `/tmp/codelite-exec.sh` under the UPDATE section in the question. Where can I find the contents of the `Makefile` ? I thought `Makefile` was the Sample code?

Comment: What command are you running to compile your code? That `/tmp/codelite-exec.sh` script seems to be useless/garbage. If you just want to compile and run your code you can do this: `gcc main.c` , to compile, and `./a.out` to run the code. I know that doesn't answer your question about codelite, but ...

Comment: Yes, I realize I can do it straight from the CLI but I am trying to follow along with this course which is using CodeLite. Furthermore, I am not running any command to compile my code, at least not manually; Codelite is compiling and executing everything for me.

Comment: Ahh... I see. What is in this file: `/Users/link/Desktop/c_code/build-Debug/bin/Sample` perhaps this is expected to make the lib directory that is missing?

Comment: `/Users/link/Desktop/c_code/build-Debug/bin/Sample` is Mach-O 64-bit executable

Answer (score 3):

I've just run into the same problem trying to build a simple wxWidgets HelloWorld with CodeLite before I do anything serious with it. It turns out that this is caused by a default project setting. Open the settings (by right-clicking on your project and selecting settings at the bottom, in case you haven't found this yet). In the General page, find the Execution group and look for Working Directory. It defaults to "$(WorkspacePath)/build-$(WorkspaceConfiguration)/lib", which is pretty silly since that won't be created by default. I changed "/lib" to "/bin" and that error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem in Codelite when trying to run a C++ program. Creating an empty folder named `lib` under the `build-Debug` folder solved the issue for me.